# Is there a Google Penalty for duplicate content example.com/ and www.example.com/?

Tags: subdomain, duplicate-content, canonical-url, no-www

I just started using SEOMoz Pro and they warned that I have duplicate content because a browser can arrive at `wwww.example.com` and `example.com`  and get to the same page.

(We use *Web.com* and they don't provide 301 redirect capability).

*Web.com* recommended using an A record instead of a CNAME record. I'm not sure if that will solve the problem.

Comment: CNAME versus A records has nothing to do with the matter. If you cannot redirect, then you MUST use a canonical link on each page from www to non-www or vice versa. If you cannot create a canonical link, then switch hosts tomorrow! There is no excuse for not being able to redirect and not being able to have a canonical link. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en Cheers!!

Comment: I still feel it's pretty stupid from Google to view www.mysite and mysite as two different entities I mean.... So much for common sense.

Comment: "We use Web.com" - do you mean `webs.com`?

Comment: @w3dk No, web.com